# Creating a View of Only Childless Comments

Tags: 7, comments, views

We have a support system in which one user can request help or insight from another user by selecting that user from a dropdown list, which is an additional field in each comment. I am attempting to create a view which will display *only* those comments which have both:

1. requested the authenticated user's attention
2. have *not* been responded to by the authenticated user.

In essence, **I want to create a view of comments which haven't been replied to by the authenticated user.** (The first filter is simple and I already have working.)

The problem I'm encountering is, although Views has a Parent-Comment Relationship, it has no Child-Comment Relationship. So I can use that relationship to either gain access to comments who have or do not have parent comments, I can not use this to determine if the comment itself is a parent (that I know of).

Comment: What is the comment depth?

Comment: There's no set comment depth. They will _likely_ be at a depth of 0 in the comments, however someone may request the attention of another user at any comment depth. Does the depth make a difference?

Comment: I think that instead of adding comments, you may add a related node (one node for each comment) then you will have total views control. Entity reference module will do the trick. Maybe you'll need rules.